# Shap summary plots for XGBoost with categorical data inputs

Tags: python, xgboost, shap

XGBoost supports inputting features as categories directly, which is very useful when there are a lot of categorical variables. This doesn't seem to be compatible with Shap:

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost
import shap

# Test data
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']})
test_data['feature_2'] = test_data['feature_2'].astype('category')

# Fit xgboost
model = xgboost.XGBRegressor(enable_categorical=True,
                                       tree_method='hist')
model.fit(test_data.drop('target', axis=1), test_data['target'] )

# Explain with Shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_data)
```

Throws an error: **ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category.**

Is it possible to use Shap in this situation?

Comment: type cast to what?

Comment: There's an example above. Turing categorical data to a float is not a good idea, the data is not numeric. It's not a classification problem, it's regression... but that is irrelevant. The question is specifically for shap with categorical inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,
generating shap values with xgboost using categorical variables is an open issue. See, f.e.,  https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/2662

Given your specific example, I made it run using Dmatrix as input of shap (Dmatrix is the basic data type input of xgboost models, see the Learning API. The sklearn api, that you are using, doesn't need the Dmatrix, at least for training):

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
import shap

# Test data
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']})
test_data['feature_2'] = test_data['feature_2'].astype('category')
print(test_data.info())
# Fit xgboost
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(enable_categorical=True,
                                       tree_method='hist')
model.fit(test_data.drop('target', axis=1), test_data['target'] )

# Explain with Shap
test_data_dm = xgb.DMatrix(data=test_data.drop('target', axis=1), label=test_data['target'], enable_categorical=True)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_data_dm)
print(shap_values)
```

But the ability to generate shap values when there are categorical variables is very unstable: f.e., if you add other parameters in the xgboost you get the error "Check failed: !HasCategoricalSplit()", which is the error referenced in my first link

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
import shap

# Test data
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']})
test_data['feature_2'] = test_data['feature_2'].astype('category')
print(test_data.info())
# Fit xgboost
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(colsample_bylevel= 0.7, 
                             enable_categorical=True,
                             tree_method='hist')
model.fit(test_data.drop('target', axis=1), test_data['target'] )

# Explain with Shap
test_data_dm = xgb.DMatrix(data=test_data.drop('target', axis=1), label=test_data['target'], enable_categorical=True)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_data_dm)
shap_values
```

I've searched for a solution for months but, to conclude, as for my understanding, it is not really possible yet to generate shap values with xgboost and categorical variables (I hope someone can contradict me, with a reproducible example).
I suggest you try with the Catboost

########################## EDIT ############################

An example with Catboost

```
import pandas as pd
import catboost as cb
import shap

# Test data
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']})
test_data['feature_2'] = test_data['feature_2'].astype('category')
print(test_data.info())

model = cb.CatBoostRegressor(iterations=100)
model.fit(test_data.drop('target', axis=1), test_data['target'],
                    cat_features=['feature_2'], verbose=False)

# Explain with Shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_data.drop('target', axis=1))
shap_values
print('shap values: \n',shap_values)
```

Comment: Thanks. So Catboost is supported with categorical inputs and also works with Shap? Have you got a reference for that?

Comment: Sure,I forgot to post it in the original question, I made an edit, let me know

Answer (score 1):

I used GradientBoostingRegressor and reshaped the array into 2 features per element

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import shap
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']
                  })

df["feature_1"]=df["feature_1"].astype(int)
df["target"]=df["target"].astype(int)

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df["feature_2"]=encoder.fit_transform(df["feature_2"])

print(df)
SEED=42
    model = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=300, max_depth=8, random_state=SEED)

scale= StandardScaler()

#X=df[["feature_1","feature_2"]]
columns=["feature_1","feature_2"]
n_features=len(columns)
X=np.array(scale.fit_transform(df[columns])).reshape(-1,n_features)
y=np.array(df["target"])
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df)

print(shap_values)


y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

x=np.arange(len(X_test))
plt.bar(x,y_test)
plt.bar(x,y_pred,color='green')
plt.show()
```

output:

```
target  feature_1  feature_2
0      23         38          0
1      42         83          1
2      58         38          0
3      29         28          2
4      28         57          0

Shap values

[[-4.65720266 -3.00946401  0.        ]
 [ 2.32860133 -3.00946401  0.        ]
 [ 2.32860133 -3.00946401  0.        ]
 [-4.65720266 -3.00946401  0.        ]
 [-4.65720266 -3.00946401  0.        ]]
```

or

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'target':[23,42,58,29,28],
                      'feature_1' : [38, 83, 38, 28, 57],
                      'feature_2' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','A']
                  })

df["feature_1"]=df["feature_1"].astype(int)
df["target"]=df["target"].astype(int)

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df["feature_2"]=encoder.fit_transform(df["feature_2"])

SEED=42
#model = xgboost.XGBRegressor(enable_categorical=True,tree_method='hist')
model=xgboost.XGBRegressor(enable_categorical=True,tree_method='hist')
#model = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=SEED)

scale= StandardScaler()

#X=df[["feature_1","feature_2"]]
columns=["feature_1","feature_2"]
n_features=len(columns)
X=np.array(scale.fit_transform(df[columns])).reshape(-1,n_features)
y=np.array(df["target"])
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.6,random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
print(shap_values)


y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

x=np.arange(len(X_test))
plt.bar(x,y_test)
plt.bar(x,y_pred,color='green')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a reply. Unfortunately I am not keen on applying a label encoder to categorical data as this implies there is some order to the data for it to be effective. In the case with many categorical variables this is likely to have a significant impact on performance. Target encoding I think it a more likely solution

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are not one-hot-encoding your categorical features to begin with? [XGBoost Categorical Variables: Dummification vs encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265102/xgboost-categorical-variables-dummification-vs-encoding?rq=1)

Especially given the fact that you want to generate SHAP values later?

If you can one-hot-encode... here is a nice description of subsequent SHAP value interpretation for categorical features (https://towardsdatascience.com/shap-for-categorical-features-7c63e6a554ea), which involves inspecting both the summed SHAP value for the categories of the original feature and boxplots of SHAP values of individual categories.